# How can I get the max column value from every table in multiple schemas?

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, union

Is it possible to get the max value of a single column which exists in the majority of tables within several different schemas?

If this were one or two tables, I could easily use:

```
SELECT 'schema1.table1' as rowsource, category, max(date_used) max_date_used from schema1.table1 group by category
UNION ALL
SELECT 'schema1.table2' as rowsource, category, max(date_used) max_date_used from schema1.table2 group by category
UNION ALL
SELECT 'schema2.table3' as rowsource, category, max(date_used) max_date_used from schema2.table3 group by category
UNION ALL
SELECT 'schema3.table4' as rowsource, category, max(date_used) max_date_used from schema3.table4 group by category
```

However, I am looking at having to query nearly 300 tables across 3 different schemas.

TIA for any advice/insight!

Comment: Create stored procedure which iterates over INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS and performs these queries using dynamic SQL. PS. You cannot distinguish what table each output row is taken from, so the query makes no sense. Add one more column like `SELECT ... , 'schemaX.tableY' as taken_from ...`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to store all your required table from informationSchema into a temp table, then use Dynamic SQL to go through each one of it. For example

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Temp
CREATE TABLE #temp ---identity column will be used to iterate
(
id INT IDENTITY,
TableName VARCHAR(50),
SchemaName VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO #temp
SELECT TABLE_NAME,TABLE_SCHEMA
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
-- choose your own results with where conditions

DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @Count INT = 1
DECLARE @SchemaName VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @Table VARCHAR(20)

WHILE @COUNT <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #temp) 
BEGIN
    SELECT @SchemaName = SchemaName FROM  #temp WHERE id = @Count
    SELECT @table = TABLENAME FROM #temp WHERE id = @Count

    SELECT @sql = @sql + 'SELECT category, max(date_used) max_date_used from ' + @SchemaName + '.' + @Table + ' group by category
                   UNION ALL '

SET @Count = @Count + 1
END
PRINT LEFT((@SQL),LEN(@SQL) - LEN('UNION ALL '))
```

After you check the printed result, change it to EXEC if you think that is correct for you.